# How to schedule an apex batch class on every 15th and last day of the month?

Tags: apex, batch, cron

I have used cron expression -> '0 1 12 15,L * ?' for scheduling the batch class at 12:01 am on every 15th and last day of the month. But it is erroring out.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Use it twice
(0 1 0 15 * ?)
(0 1 0 L * ?)

I haven’t tried, but it should work!